# Asymptotics and limits of second order ODE which depend on (two) parameters

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

Dear Mathematica community, for this second order ODE:

```
h''[x] Sinh[2 x] + h'[x] 2 Cosh[2 x] - 2 h[x] Tanh[x] == 0,
```

which is basically the harmonic equation for the radial part in certain non-Euclidean metric, I need

```
Limit[h'[x] Sinh[2 x]/2, x -> Infinity]
```

or even better, express the asymptotic of `h[x]` and `h'[x]` in terms of exponential functions as `x -> Infinity`. I only need the largest term. In my home edition this asymptotic of `h'[x] as x-> Infinity` exceeds Recursion depth and Mathematica stops, unfortunately. Plug in the initial condition `h'[0]=0` also stops Mathematica. For the above limit I get `0`. Now generally the ODE depends on 2 parameters

```
h''[x] Sinh[2 x] + h'[x] 2 Cosh[2 x] - 2 m^2 h[x] Tanh[x]/a^2 == 0
```

Here `m` is a natural number, a is a small positive number. I want to find an upper of

```
Limit[a^2 h'[x] Sinh[2 x]/2, x -> Infinity]
```

which I hope can convince me that as `a->0`, the limit is `0` (or the limit is `0` regardless of `a^2`. Using approximation, like replacing `Sinh[x]` by `Exp[x]`, I get a solution whose asymptotic computation does not exceed recursion limit:

```
{{TerminatedEvaluation[
"RecursionLimit"] -> -((
 Sqrt[E^(-2 x)] BesselI[1, Sqrt[2] Sqrt[E^(-2 x)]] C[1])/Sqrt[
 2]) + Sqrt[2] Sqrt[E^(-2 x)]
  BesselK[1, Sqrt[2] Sqrt[E^(-2 x)]] C[2]}}
```

But still my Mathematica cannot handle it when it has extra parameters `a` or `m`.
More importantly, theoretically I am not sure at this moment approximating ODE with another ODE gives me a solution with the same asymptotic. Thank you!

Comment: If you want  `h[x]` as `x-> Infinity` try: `AsymptoticDSolveValue[{h''[x] Sinh[2 x] + h'[x] 2 Cosh[2 x] - 
    2 h[x] Tanh[x] == 0, h'[0] == 0}, h[x], {x, Infinity, 1}]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find the solution $h(x)$ and then use `Asymptotic` on its derivative?

```
ode = h''[x] Sinh[2 x] + h'[x] 2 Cosh[2 x] - 2 h[x] Tanh[x] == 0
sol = h[x] /. First@DSolve[ode, h[x], x]
res = D[sol, x]*Sinh[2*x]/2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Asymptotic[res, x -> Infinity] // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you. In general, Mathematica can only give series solutions to ODE. So I am still not sure whether with two parameters, it can give a series solutions. But this expansion alone is helpful! Just have to dive into MeijerG.